# Kickstart HTML editor toolbar

Tags: javascript, html, toolbar, html5-kickstart

I have a requirement to make HTML editor in my website like Bold,Italic ,Unnderline,Left allign etc.My question is that if Kickstarter provides HTML editor toolbar or not? I have searched in google and find Nicedit HTML editor which provides HTML editor toolbar but I want to use kickstarter for HTML editor toolbar.Please suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nicedit with HTML Kickstart no problem. It's also easy to customize the CSS for Nicedit if you want it to look more like Kickstart. Just add the Nicedit CSS and JS files to your HTML file.